# .desktop file does not load python executable if other python program is imported

Tags: python, pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04

I wrote a PyQt4 application in my Example.py file and made it executable. Then, I created an Example.desktop file in Ubuntu calling this executable. It worked. Afterwards, I wanted to add a function from another python file Example_2.py by importing it in Example.py like so:

```
 from Example_2 import *
```

It runs perfectly well if I run it in a command line window by typing

```
 $python Example.py
```

but the Example.desktop file does not open anymore. Besides, other standard modules included in the original Example.py file, like

```
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *,
```

do not compromise the functioning of the Example.desktop file.

Can somebody help?

Edit: The content of the Example.desktop file is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Example
Exec=/home/workspace/Example.py
Terminal=False
Type=Application
```

Both Python files are in /home/workspace

Comment: How did you generate the executable?

Comment: sudo chmod -x Example.py, same with Example_2.py

Comment: What is the content of your .desktop and where are the .py files?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Is there nothing between /usr/bin/python and home/workspace/Example.py? Copy/Paste from "to" onwards does not work.

Comment: change to `Exec=/usr/bin/python /home/workspace/Example.py &`

Comment: `Exec= path_of_your_python  path_of_your_script`

Comment: Some things happen to me when typing, test it and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. What do you suspect the error to be?

Comment: When I try to replicate your error I got the following in the log of my OS: `/path/of/script.py: line XXX: from: command not found`

Comment: Try adding a working directory path to your `Desktop Entry`: `Path=/home/workspace`

Comment: In your code are you using absolute or relative paths?

Comment: @ eyllanesc: I am sorry, but I realized that the problem is not directly with the other file in general, but with a sqlite3 connection that seems to cause this problem. Thanks for your help. I will merge the question, so if you can answer, do it there.